# Probability calculation when rolling a 6 sided dice

Tags: probability

this is a newbie question but I can't seem to get to the answer right.

The scenario is the following - it's said (in this book I'm reading) that the probability to roll a 6-sided dice 30 times and have the number 6 as an outcome 21 of those 30 times is 0.000297.

How do they calculate this result? My calculation is obviously off, since I thought the probability must be $\frac{1}{6}^{21} * \frac{5}{6}^9$ but it obviously isn't because I'm not getting the correct number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are missing ${{30} \choose {21}}$ as those $21$ outcomes can be any $21$ of $30$ throws.

Comment: Hint: You have to use the binomial distribution with $p=\frac16, n=30$ and $k=21$. If you have any further question, leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working assume that the first $21$ outcome is $6$ and the rest are not.

You need to multiply it by $\binom{30}{21}$.

$$\binom{30}{21}\left( \frac16\right)^{21} \left( \frac56\right)^9$$

Check out binomial distribution.